# how to identify outliers in a scatterplot matrix made using splom?

Tags: r, lattice

I have data on weather variables such as temperature, rainfall etc for the period 2001-2009 for various locations in India.

To see the relationship between these variables, I create a scatterplot matrix using splom with the following code.

```
   library(lattice)
   library(RColorBrewer)
   splom(~aod_corr[c(5,8,11,14)], lower.panel = panel.splom,
  upper.panel = function(x, y, ...) {
      panel.fill(col = brewer.pal(9, "RdBu")[ round(cor(x, y) * 4 + 5)])
      panel.text(mean(x), mean(y), round(cor(x, y),2), font=2)
  },

 scales = list(x = list( draw = TRUE, cex=0.1)), type = c("g", "p", "smooth"),layout =     c(1, 1))
```

I now wish to identify the outliers in each panel that I can trace back to the data. How can I do so?

Comment: If you accept an answer it will be helpful to everybody else.  Its a nice question!!

Answer (score 5):

Seems like this is a job for the function `panel.link.splom`. See here
http://procomun.wordpress.com/2011/03/18/splomr/

Comment: I have seen the above but the code at the bottom of the page does not work for me. May be I am not using it correctly. Can you be more spefic?

Comment: Can you dput your `aod_corr` dataset (or maybe a simplified subset)?

Comment: Karsten, I ahv made some progress but its tedious. I wonder if I can improve on it.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the link given by @Karsten I give you  a sceanrio of interaction with `splom` object:

1. I plot my splom
2. I identify the panel
3. I choose some points using link splom
4. I escape to get the results

details:

1. I create a splom using lattice splom
2. Interaction:

   ```
   ## I get the focus on the major panel (red color)
   trellis.focus('panel', 1, 1)
   ## I link my panel to the splom
   idx <- panel.link.splom(pch=13, cex=0.6, col='green')
   ```
3. I choose some points with the mouse. They will colored in green
4. Escape to get the focus
5. Check the result

   ```
   str(idx)   num [1:5] 111 95 132 96 15
   ```

Comment: I have made some progress by using    panel.link.splom(verbose=TRUE) but somehow I cannot get the correlations in the splom as in the code above. I don't know why is this so?